# Nginx Returns Welcome Page Inside Docker Using Laravel & Traefik

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, traefik

I've setup Docker with a custom Nginx/PHP image for my Laravel app. I'm serving it via Traefik as I'm hosting multiple sites on one machine. Nginx only returns the `Welcome to Nginx` page when I load up the site. I've verified via `nginx -T` that my Nginx config is setup correctly. I've entered the Docker container via terminal and see all my files there. I've narrowed the issue down to `Traefik` - if I remove the Traefik tags and expose a port instead, my site shows up just fine. This is true of identically configured sites not using Traefik. I need to be able to use Traefik but have it return my Laravel app (called Laraview) instead found in `src`. Thanks for your help! Here is my config:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM justintime50/nginx-php:latest

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./src /var/www/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN php composer.phar install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-suggest --no-progress --prefer-dist

RUN chmod -R 775 storage \
    && php artisan storage:link \
    && chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.7"
services:

    laraview:
        build: .
        restart: always
        container_name: laraview
        volumes: 
            # - ./src:/var/www/html # Only use for development
            - ./src/.env:/var/www/html/.env
            - ./src/storage/logs:/var/www/html/storage/logs
            - ./src/storage/app/public:/var/www/html/storage/app/public
        networks:
            - traefik
            - laraview
        labels:
            - traefik.enabled=true
            - traefik.docker.network=traefik
            - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:laraview.localhost
            - traefik.port=80
        env_file:
            - init-db.env
        depends_on:
            - laraview-db

    laraview-db:
        image: mysql:5.7.26
        restart: always
        container_name: laraview-db
        env_file:
            - init-db.env
        volumes:
            - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - laraview
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        labels:
            - traefik.enable=false

networks:
    traefik:
        external:
            name: traefik
    laraview:
        name: laraview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
traefik.enabled=true
```

should be

```
traefik.enable=true
```

Also 
`server_name localhost;` doesn't match your hostname in the docker-compose

Comment: Although the Traefik piece wasn't the answer, it was something to fix as well. It came down to the server_name not matching. Thanks!